# Function and local martingale

Tags: calculus, functions, martingales, local-martingales

Is there exist non-negative continuously differentiable function $g$, such that the process $(g(t)W_t^2)_{t \geq 0}$ is local martingale?

I know that i need Ito formula, but how i know which function i should take?

Comment: Apply Itô's formula to calculate the stochastic differential of $X_t := g(t) W_t^2$ (for general $g$) and then choose $g$ such that the $ds$-term becomes zero.

Comment: So, then how i calculate $[g(t), W_t^2]$ or i don't have quadratic variation?

Comment: Itô's formula tells you how to calculate the stochastic differential of a process of the form $X_t = f(t,W_t)$. All you need are the derivatives of $f=f(t,x)$ with respect to $t$ and $x$. Find the suitable function $f$ and apply Itô's formula.

Comment: just to be sure it's ok:
if i apply Ito's formula then i get $$dX_t = g'(t)W_t^2dt + g(t)2W_tdW_t^2 + \frac{1}{2} g'(t)4W_t^2dt = 3g'(t)W_t dt + 2g(t)W_tdW_t^2$$. So then i get $g'(t) = 0$, so i can take $g(t) = t$?

Comment: No, not exactly. First of all, it should read $dW_t$ instead of $dW_t^2$. Moreover, the 3rd term, i.e. $$\frac{1}{2} g'(t) 4 W_t^2 \, dt$$ is not correct.

Comment: Thanks. Then how is correct?

Comment: You tell me... just check your calculations... it's not that difficult to calculate a second derivative, is it?

Comment: so if i don't make some mistake in calculation the 3rd term is $g(t)dt$, correct? But then i get that there no exist non-negative function?

Comment: Well, it's $2 g(t) \, dt$ but that doesn't change much. Your conclusion is fine.

Comment: Thank for your help :)